# Angular2 Material2 - How to disable/enable mat-datepicker-toggle on form rebuild

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-material2

**Angular version 5.2.4, Material2 5.2.4**

I am using this combination of elements:

- mat-formfield
- input with a matinput directive
- mat-datepicker
- mat-datepicker-toggle

...in a form that rebuilds when the datasource changes.

I am able to set the input and the mat-datepicker-toggle to disabled, or enabled, in the initial form build. When the form is rebuilt, the disabled property of the input is settable. However, the disabled property of the mat-datepicker-toggle remains at the initial state (whether that is enabled, or disabled) for any form rebuilds after the initial form build.

[Material documentation](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#disabling-parts-of-the-datepicker) states (I am using quotation marks around the elements here):

> As with any standard "input element", it is possible to disable the datepicker input by adding the disabled property. By default, the "mat-datepicker" and "mat-datepicker-toggle" will inherit their disabled state from the "input element"

So, setting the disabled/ enabled state of the mat-datepicker-toggle **after** rebuilding the form is the problem I am trying to solve.

I have simplified, but working, code below to show what I have tried most recently. Let me know if there is more information you require.

#### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule,} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [ MatDatepickerModule, MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule, MatNativeDateModule ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, 
MaterialModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { VERSION } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  version = VERSION;
  disableMe = false;
  infamousDate = "2018-08-22T12:34:56.789Z";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rebuildForm();
  }
  rebuildForm() {
    this.disableMe = !this.disableMe;
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      dateJoined: new FormControl(
        { disabled: this.disableMe, value: this.infamousDate })
    });
  }
}
```

#### app.component.html

```
<form class="basic-container" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateJoined" placeholder="Date joined" formControlName="dateJoined">
    <mat-datepicker #dateJoined></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateJoined"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button (click)="rebuildForm()">click me</button><hr><span>date enabled: {{!disableMe}}</span>
```

Here is the same code in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang5-mat-datepicker-toggle-disable-not-changing-on-formbuild?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the disabled input of the mat-datepicker-toggle to the form control's disabled property:

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateJoined"
    [disabled]="formGroup.controls['dateJoined'].disabled">
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

Comment: @GTrantor This works perfectly. Thanks for the clear answer, G.